# Can a web application be converted to a google chrome application?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

We have a very simple digital signage application that loads six web pages and rotates through them in an iframe.

We thought we would like to take this application and run in kiosk mode as a chromium app. However, simply using the HTML in the page has thrown all kinds of errors for the app. The most consistent on is the illegal use of external images, css, and fonts as well as complaints about javascript libraries, etc.

It looks as though it will be extremely painful to try to make this into a kiosk app.

Is it possible to make this type of conversion?

Does anyone have advice as to how to proceed?

Can you pull in external pages into a Chromium app?

Comment: [Webview](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview).

Answer (score -2):

You cannot run Javascript on a browser via local filesystem for security reasons. But what you could do is package the web app as a local app.

One option is to use Windows HTML Application (HTA)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application

But this requires Internet Explorer to run.

Another option that sounds great is using Node Webkit. I have never done it before, but seems very powerful.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodewebkit

You can write a powerful Javascript app and run it locally this way.

**UPDATE**
Official Node Webkit website:

http://nwjs.io/

Comment: Useless answer, considering the question is specifically about Chrome Apps platform.

Comment: @Xan:  "Is it possible to make this type of conversion?" = "can I run a web app as a desktop app in a local kiosk; we've tried something that didn't work, and we are thinking about using chromium app".
But I am glad you took your time to provide some input.